# Clicking on an image in a collection view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have a collection view and each item has an image and a label. I want to click the `NSCollectionViewItem` or `NSImage` and then hide the collection view and display a completely separate view containing the details of the object that was clicked.

I cant find any documentation on how to handle click events in this situation. How is this possible? I have built out the collection view in Interface Builder so everything was done via bindings as opposed to code.

Comment: Check this for the answer to your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541572/selection-highlight-in-nscollectionview

Comment: I dont see the connection between that post and handling mouse clicks. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I went with was to not actually use an `Image Well`, aka `NSImage`. I used a button and bound the `Image` property to an instance of an `NSImage` that I exposed as a property on my model.

It was easy enough but I'm shocked more people havent been asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeff, I don't have permissions to add a comment so writing this as answer.

You can overwrite setSelection in your subclass of NSCollectionViewItem (as explained by @indragie in [Selection Highlight in NSCollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541572/selection-highlight-in-nscollectionview)) to track the selected item and perform an action.