# Unable to get selected item of collection view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm having a problem trying to get the selection of my Collection View using Xcode 6 and trying to build an OSX app.

I followed the directions at http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/Introduction/Introduction.html to create the collection view and it's working as intended but I am unable to get the selection of the item I click.  I made sure that the view is selectable in IB.

I implemented the notification method mentioned in [Selection Highlight in NSCollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541572/selection-highlight-in-nscollectionview) and I can see when I populate the collection view that the event fires but no matter where I click in the collection view item the notification won't fire again.

As is what I think normal for collection views, I'm simply trying to get the array index of the item selected so I can show detail.

I have poured through articles on the net trying to find the solution but the vast majority of solutions are for IOS using segue's and not for OSX.  The exception being the link I posted for Stack Overflow.

I've even gone as far as putting a transparent button covering my entire collection view item so I can grab a click event (which works but I still don't know which item was clicked).

My my question is: how do I get the array item of something I clicked in a collection view?

[image]

Comment: **If** all the bindings are correct (see answer below), this kind of behaviour can be due to one of the key objects being deallocated = ensure that all of the objects involved (e.g. the ``NSIndexSet`` instance that is being observed, and the object that owns this index set are objects that are retained (like properties). One way of checking this is to add a button to the UI, and, in the associated *Action* method, log the objects of interest. If one of these objects outputs ``nil`` as its description, this is possibly the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of hearing about changes to the array controllers `selectionIndexes` is to bind this property to an `NSIndexSet` instance in your code somewhere, and then use the KVO design pattern to request a notification when this `NSIndexSet` is altered.  If you set this up correctly, when the user clicks on an unselected cell in your `NSCollectionView` the `NSIndexSet` that the array controller is using to store its selection indexes is updated. Since this index set is the one you're observing, you'll get a notification telling you about the change.

In the demo-app I created to answer this question, I placed the index set in question on the `AppDelegate` - here's the implementation file:

```
// Interface ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@interface AppDelegate ()

// This is the content array from which the NSArrayController will derive
// it's arrangedObjects array
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *collectionViewContent;

// This is the NSIndexSet that I want the NSArrayController to use
// to store its selectionIndexes.
@property (nonatomic) NSIndexSet *mySelectionIndexes;

@end

// Implementation //////////////////////////////////////////////////

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    // The content that will be shown in the NSCollectionView (each word
    // represents a single collection view item).
    self.collectionViewContent = @[@"The", @"rain", @"in", @"Spain", @"falls", @"..."];

    // Tell cocoa you want to know when the array controller makes changes to
    // the index set it's using to stores its selection indexes
    [self addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"mySelectionIndexes"
              options:0
              context:nil];
}


-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                     ofObject:(id)object
                       change:(NSDictionary *)change
                      context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"Collection view selection just changed to: %@", self.mySelectionIndexes);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

In the *Bindings Inspector* for the `NSArrayController` you can now tell the array controller to use the `AppDelegate` property `mySelectionIndexes` to store its selection indexes:

[image]

If you're still experiencing problems, it's possible that you've gone wrong with the bindings somewhere else - here are all the bindings I used:

**NSArrayController**
The array controller will get it's content from an array managed by the `AppDelegate` object. It will store it's selection indexes in an `NSIndexSet`, also managed by the `AppDelegate`

1. Content Array: App Delegate.collectionViewContent
2. Selection Indexes: App Delegate.mySelectionIndexes

**NSCollectionView**
The collection view will get it's model data from the array controller. It will mark as *selected* those views that appear at the indexes stored in the array controller's `selectionIndexes` property:

1. Content: Array Controller.arrangedObjects
2. Selection Indexes: Array Controller.selectionIndexes

Onto the view that was automatically generated when I dragged the `NSCollectionView` onto the canvas, I've added one `NSTextField`, this text field has just one binding:

1. Value: Collection View Item.representedObject (In other words, type *representedObject* into the *Model Key Path* field.

### A Final Word:

It's worth pointing out that you don't *have* to set up this binding. To get word when one of the items in your collection view is selected or unselected by the user, create a subclass of `NSCollectionViewItem` and override the `selected` setter. This property is called automatically each time an item is selected or unselected. In your implementation, you can now make adjustments to the item's view to take account of the fact that it's status has changed. In my demo-app, my custom subclass of `NSCollectionViewItem` was called `PPCollectionViewItem`:

```
@implementation PPCollectionViewItem

-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    // Call super...
    [super setSelected:selected];

    // ...now change the view associated with this item. Remember,
    // the view is one of the cells in the NSCollectionView - I
    // changed it from a standard NSView, to a subclass called
    // CollectionViewCell which keeps a flag indicating whether
    // or not it's selected (the drawRect routine is varied
    // according to this flag's value).
    [(CollectionViewCell *)self.view setDrawAsSelected:selected];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question in what looks like a great solution!  My problem is still the same as originally, though, in that your observeValueForKeyPath method gets called when I'm populating the array but clicking on a collection view item doesn't trigger it at all.  Again, I have made sure IB shows the collection view is selectable.  I haven't tried the 2nd solution yet of a custom class but I'm wondering if what I'm dealing with is something else that prevents me from knowing that something go selected at all.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an exhaustive list of the other bindings in the project. I think you're right to avoid the second solution until you've got the first one working. In the simplest case, you only need to implement the ``AppDelegate`` as described, add a text field to the ``Collection View`` and get the bindings right.

Comment: So it appears that what I missed in all of this was to bind the collection view to the array controller (Selection Indexes: Array Controller.selectionIndexes) and that did the trick.  Thank you so much for your help, I was at a complete stopping point until this!!!!!

Comment: Selection Indexes: Array Controller.selectionIndexes - I incorrectly had as key selection only